# How to finish an aborted Ubuntu subsystem initialization?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed the Ubuntu subsystem with 18.04 on Windows 10. The installation was apparently stuck at ~"Installing...", but when I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> the output ~"Please enter a new UNIX username:" was shown and the key press was taken as confirmation for an empty username. The installation then hang further and I had to close the window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

When I start the Ubuntu subsystem I get a prompt for root which makes me think that the initialization didn't succeed. How can I complete/restart it?

Comment: Have you tried to simply uninstall it through the Windows Store and install it again?

Comment: @Ramhound That solves the issue, I feel dumb for not seeing this solution. I'd accept that as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: I have already submitted an answer on how to Reset or Uninstall WSL instance.   I will find the duplicate question and simple flag this question instead of submitting the same answer again.

Comment: @Ramhound There is another way to add default user without uninstalling.

Comment: @Biswapriyo The initialization might do more than add a user.

Comment: Link: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL-DistroLauncher/blob/master/DistroLauncher/DistroLauncher.cpp

Comment: @Biswapriyo - If you want to answer this question answer the duplicate question.